# Problems runnning Mad Max full screen

Tags: pc, mad-max

If I attempt to play *Mad Max* on the PC in full screen, the colours of the game, menu's etc become very bright, discoloured and generally unpleasant, to the point of it being basically unplayable.

As a temporary work around I am playing the game in borderless windowed, but I would like to know what is causing this issue and how to fix it in order to play it full screen. Is anyone else having this issue?

I am using a GeForce GTX660 with up-to-date drivers, and I have already verified the games cache through Steam.

Comment: Have you calibrated your monitor and saved a profile? Some games cannot/do not honor monitor calibration in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Yorik I have no idea what you mean by this, so no, I don't think I have.

Comment: ( https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/501853/nvidia-forever-ignoring-custom-color-profile-support-in-full-screen-games-collaboration-thread-/ )

Comment: (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display ) All monitors display colors differently and some people ramp the brightness and contrast pretty high on the front panel. It seems that this game is basically changing/disabling the windows-set or driver-set gamma, brightness, and contrast and exposing monitor overadjustment. You might try going through the calibration process at the OS level (not using nvidia control panel). This may look a little dimmer than you are used to at first, but it may lessen the difference between the game and the OS.

Comment: @Yorik I appreciate the help and the link, but I don't think this is my issue. The problem I am seeing seems to be far to severe for that to be the case.